# Why is singleton class' __init__() method called twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why `foo` is printed twice?

```
class A:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, *, var):
        print('foo')
        self.var = var

a = A(var=1)
b = A(var=2)

assert a == b
assert a.var == b.var
```

Comment: Because `__init__` gets called every time,  after `__new__`. The fact that you make `__new__` return the same object does not stop `__init__` from being executed.

Comment: If `__new__` is going to return existing objects, `__init__` should be a no-op.

Comment: You'd be better off with just `assert a is b`

Answer (score 3):

When you write `A(...)`, you are calling

```
type.__call__(A, ...)
```

That's because `type` is the metaclass of `A`. `type.__call__` will call `__new__` and `__init__` in sequence. `__init__` will always be called if `__new__` returns an instance of the class. Here is a simplified view:

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    self = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(self, cls):
        cls.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return self
```

The simplest way I can think of making a singleton work this way is to put all your initialization logic into `__new__`:

```
class A:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *, var):
        if cls._instance is None:
            self = super().__new__(cls)
            self.var = var
            cls._instance = self

        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('foo')
```

Sure, `foo` still gets printed every time you ask for a new instance, but it's well and truly a singleton.

A more comprehensive approach is to override the behavior of your metaclass `__call__` method. That will avoid calling `__init__` except once:

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(cls, '_instance'):
            return cls._instance
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

class A(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, *, var):
        print('foo')
        self.var = var
```

Comment: How are you passing `var` to `__new__()`?

Comment: @UmbertoFontanazza. The call is exactly as in the question: for example `a = A(var=1)`. Anything you pass to `__call__` should be passed through to `__new__` and `__init__`, unless your metaclass intercepts it.